# Plot sparse data with hexadecimal labels using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, hex, sparse-matrix, label

I want to plot sparse data using sparse scales with pretty hexadecimal labels using ggplot2 in GNU R.
I have a data frame and a label function similar to the following:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(src = round(c(0x10000:0x10100,runif(100, 0x1000,0x100000))),
                 dst = round(c(0x11000:0x11100,runif(100,0x1000,0x100000))))
hexlabels=function(x) {base::sprintf("0x%x",as.integer(x))}
```

The key is that the data is very sparsely spreaded over a wide range. 
Additionally there is a mix of dense areas with sparse areas.

A basic point plot `ggplot(df, aes(x = src, y = dst)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(labels = hexlabels) + scale_y_continuous(labels = hexlabels)` does not represent the dense part of the plot in an adquate manner and the hexadecimal labels are positioned at unfortunate breaks.

To solve the first problem, I have therefore tried to use discrete scales with a conversion to factors:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(src), y = factor(dst))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = hexlabels) +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = hexlabels)
```

This result is a plot that shows an adequate representation of the points, but completely unreadable discrete scales.

I have so far used indices to return to continuous scales to get a readable result, but without meaningful labels.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(factor(src)),
               y = as.numeric(factor(dst)))) + geom_point()
```

Can you give me hints how to realize this plot, with similar scales, but using the original `src` and `dst` values as labels on the axes, possibly with pretty breaks for hexadecimal values?

So far i have unsuccessfully tried to convert my `src` and `dst` data to separate preprocessed data frames (reference likes):

```
require(scales)
as.referencelike <- function(x) { 
    data.frame(ref = x, idx = as.numeric(as.factor(x))) }
df$rlsrc = as.referencelike(df$src)
df$rldst = as.referencelike(df$dst)
referencelike_trans <- trans_new("referencelike", 
    transform = function(x) {x$idx}, 
    inverse = identity)
ggplot(df, aes(x = rlsrc, y = rldst)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = referencelike_trans) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = referencelike_trans)
```

This results in the error that `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (357): x, y`, probably because ggplot takes the lengths of the small data frames, and does not check the transformation.
Also, the inverse transformation still needs to be implemented.
The specified transformation does not actually seem to be called.

My second try was to create a custom class:

```
require(scales)
reference <- setClass("reference", slots = c("ref","idx"))
as.reference <- function(y) { 
    i = as.numeric(as.factor(y))
    Map(function(a,b) { 
        reference(ref = a, idx = b) }, y, i)}
df$rsrc = as.reference(df$src)
df$rdst = as.reference(df$dst)
reference_trans <- trans_new("reference", 
    transform = function(x) {x@idx}, 
    inverse = identity)
as.data.frame.reference <- function(x,...) { data.frame(ref = x@ref, idx = x@idx, ...) }
ggplot(df, aes(x = rsrc, y = rdst)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = reference_trans) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = reference_trans)
```

At this point I get the following error: `Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y`

So far I have not tried to implement a `pretty_breaks` variant for hexadecimal data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working code for this example:

```
hexbreaks <- function(x) {
    n = 5
    x<-as.numeric(x); 
    mask =0
    for(i in seq(30,0)) {
        mask = bitwOr(mask,2**i)
        masked = bitwAnd(x,mask)
        count = sum(masked==x)
        if(count >=n) {
            return(masked[masked==x])
        }
    }
    c(min(x),median(x),max(x))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(src), y = factor(dst))) + geom_point() + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=hexbreaks, labels=hexlabels) +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=hexbreaks, labels=hexlabels)
```